# Filling Generalpath results in unwanted results

Tags: java, graphics, graphics2d, fill, polyline

For later creation of randomized particles (in a game) i created functions, who take the segments of an ellipse, customize them and later draw them. This works well with g.draw(...the_line..) [The Ellipse outer_Bounds get drawn], but as soon as i use g.fill(...the_line...) the inner part is not being filled correct.

HOW TO FIX : Wrong moveto points... Just move the moveto-statements in the initial pi.SEG_Moveto

[The resulting graphic (ignore the number and the little box behind it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V63Ve.png)

```
private Ellipse2D.Double oval=new Ellipse2D.Double(100, 100, 100, 100);
private ArrayList<double[]> Ellipse_Generation_Points = new ArrayList<double[]>();
private double [] vals = new double[6];

public void Projectile_Basis(){
    for (PathIterator pi = oval.getPathIterator(null); !pi.isDone(); pi.next()){

        //currentSegment übergibt Type und Koordinatenpaare
        int type = pi.currentSegment(vals);
        //System.out.println(type);

        //Überprüfung des Übergebenen Types, Unterschiedliche Typen geben eine unterschiedliche Anzahl an Koordinaten-Paaren an
        //Type benötigt, um später die Form korrekt nachzuzeichnen
        if (type==pi.SEG_MOVETO||type==pi.SEG_LINETO) {
            double [] pathIteratorCoords = {type, vals[0], vals[1]};
            Ellipse_Generation_Points.add(pathIteratorCoords);
        }

        else if (type==pi.SEG_QUADTO){
            double [] pathIteratorCoords = {type, vals[0], vals[1], vals[2], vals[3]};
            Ellipse_Generation_Points.add(pathIteratorCoords);
        }

        else if (type==pi.SEG_CUBICTO){
            //RANDOMIZER
            vals[0]+=Math.random()*50;
            vals[1]-=Math.random()*50;

            double [] pathIteratorCoords = {type, vals[0], vals[1], vals[2], vals[3], vals[4], vals[5]};
            Ellipse_Generation_Points.add(pathIteratorCoords);

        }

        else if (type==pi.SEG_CLOSE){
            double [] pathIteratorCoords = {type, vals[0], vals[1]};
            Ellipse_Generation_Points.add(pathIteratorCoords);
        }

    }
}

public GeneralPath Generate_Random_Particle(){
    PathIterator pi = oval.getPathIterator(null);
    double [] start_element = new double [3]; // Zum Schließen des Objekts
    double [] last_element = new double [3];

    GeneralPath polyline = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, Ellipse_Generation_Points.size());

    for(int i=0; i<Ellipse_Generation_Points.size(); i++){


        //Übergabe des Double_Arrays aus Projectile_Basis, spätere Aufteilung in die einzelnen Bausteine
        double [] current_element=Ellipse_Generation_Points.get(i);

        if (current_element[0]==PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO){

        start_element=current_element;  //MOVETO only am Start des Objekts
        last_element=current_element;   

        }

            else if (current_element[0]==PathIterator.SEG_LINETO){

                polyline.moveTo(last_element[1], last_element[2]);

                polyline.lineTo(current_element[1], current_element[2]);

                last_element[1]=current_element[1];
                last_element[2]=current_element[2];

            }
            else if (current_element[0]==PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO){

                polyline.moveTo(last_element[1], last_element[2]);

                polyline.quadTo(
                                        current_element[1], current_element[2],
                                        current_element[3], current_element[4]
                                );

                last_element[1]=current_element[3];
                last_element[2]=current_element[4];

            }
            else if (current_element[0]==PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO){

                polyline.moveTo(last_element[1], last_element[2]);

                polyline.curveTo(
                                        current_element[1], current_element[2],
                                        current_element[3], current_element[4],
                                        current_element[5], current_element[6]  
                                );

                last_element[1]=current_element[5];
                last_element[2]=current_element[6];

            }
            else if (current_element[0]==PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE){

                polyline.moveTo(start_element[1], start_element[2]);
                polyline.closePath();

            }
    }

    return polyline;
}
```

Comment: You might need to change the winding rule, check the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried changing the winding rule, but unluckily this had no effect on the effect. It remains the same problem with both winding rules.

Comment: I (believe that i) found the reasoning behind the inner region. The Path is not just the ellipse, but rather has another line at the edge of the inner region.
  1. g.draw maybe only draws the outer boundaries (therefore the lines would not be visible)
  2. the path is not getting constructed in the correct way, i have no clue why, but i'll be looking into it